# Langchain summarization: Response time error, Expecting value from correct syntax

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am trying to replicate the basic langchain summarization type = Stuff usage as on [its website documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/summarization), but it is not able to process long doc.

Test result: tried its original demo code, it did not work, and gives two types of error alternatively after dozens of trials:
**Error 1:** timeout error (I've referred to the [related langchain timeout discussion](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3005) here to increase request_timeout=600/3600 secs, but still get the timeout error. checked my host is on)

**Error 2:** Invalid response object from API
Retrying langchain.chat_models.openai.ChatOpenAI.completion_with_retry.._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised APIError: Invalid response object from API: '{"object":"error","message":"Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)","code":50001}' (HTTP response code was 400).

**Then I downsized the model from llama2-7b to "Sheared-LLaMA-1.3B" and replaced the original example's doc with shorter doc as below. I can see langchain w/ verbose started w/  `> Entering new StuffDocumentsChain chain..., > Entering new LLMChain chain...` w/ print out the original full doc, **but it returns'> Finished chain. returns "Got any creative ideas for a 10 year old’s birthday?"'**

```
model_name = "Sheared-LLaMA-1.3B"

# use load_summarize_chain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain

loader = WebBaseLoader("https://huggingface.co/princeton-nlp/Sheared-LLaMA-1.3B") 
docs = loader.load()

llm = ChatOpenAI(verbose = True
                 ,temperature=0.1
                 , model_name=model_name
                 , openai_api_key = "EMPTY" 
                 , openai_api_base = "http://localhost:8000/v1"
                 , request_timeout=600
                 , max_retries=1
)

chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff",verbose=True)
chain.run(docs)


# B. use StuffDocumentsChain
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.combine_documents.stuff import StuffDocumentsChain


prompt_template = """Write a concise summary of the following:
"{text}"
CONCISE SUMMARY:"""
prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(prompt_template)

llm = ChatOpenAI(verbose = True
                 , temperature=0.1                  
                 , model_name=model_name
                 , openai_api_key = "EMPTY"
                 , openai_api_base = "http://localhost:8000/v1"
                 , request_timeout=600
                 , max_retries=1)

llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, verbose = True)

stuff_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
    llm_chain=llm_chain, document_variable_name="text"
)

docs = loader.load()
print(stuff_chain.run(docs ))
```

Try the same code with a small piece of business related conversation doc,`StuffDocumentsChain` returns something relevant, but `load_summarize_chain` only gives
`

> Finished chain.

> Finished chain.
> '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n......
> `

The problem comes, when I double the size or my test business doc(4k words, definitely have to be>4096 tokens, that's the point of using summarization fn), it returns Error 1 and Error 2 mentioned at the beginning. so get the trouble it is not able to process long doc gain.